# Import from txt file to HashSet

Tags: java, filereader, hashset

I have been working on a program which would allow me to export data from a HashSet into a text file, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198648/write-hashset-to-txt-using-filewriter), and then in a new class import that text file into the HashSet.

I have it set so that when I write to the txt file, it's saved like this:

[image: text file]

Unfortunately, I am not exactly sure how to import it so that it gets stored correctly in a HashSet.
Would someone be able to help point me in the right direction? I know I need to import FileReader, but besides for that I am clueless.

Comment: Don't be sorry for not being able to embed an image--embed text.

Comment: What's your problem? How to read a text file? How to parse a single line from the file?

Comment: @jangroth well for starters how to set up the filereader to call the txt file to fill a HashSet (now that I think about it, that's several problems)

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<ComputerScientist> computerScientistSet = new HashSet<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filepath))){
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" , ");
        computerScientistSet.add(new ComputerScientist(line[0], line[1]));
    }
}
```

Written quick and not tested, it should give you an idea though. (Assuming I understood your question). I hope you're not bothered by the use of Scanner instead of FileReader.

Comment: Based on the code that you gave, I would not need to use FileReader then? And would there really be a difference if they both do the same thing?

Comment: A Scanner is easier to use than a FileReader (for example the option to read line by line). A good alternative for the Scanner here would be the BufferedReader, but as long as you're not multithreading both do their job just fine.

Comment: Speaking of reading line to line, the part where you have line[0], line[1] gives me the following error when I run the method:     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Probably caused by the blank line(s) at the end of your file. Everything after the " , " is filled in line[1]. If there is no " , " this will give errors. Either remove the whitelines, or check if the length of the array line equals two before adding. I was merely pointing you "in the right direction", as you asked.

Comment: And I thank you for that. Figuring out stuff (mostly) by myself is the only real way to learn. I was able to get it to run successfully, however the HashSet does not save the information. I then included a method to return the size of the HashSet, and it came back as 0. Should I update the question with the code from my class?